# FoxPro to Sql Server conversion

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, t-sql, visual-foxpro

I have a bunch of FoxPro tables that are stored locally on my machine. I want to convert the data into SQL Server. What is the best/fastest way of doing this? With the below code I can throw this into a data table. If I do this how would I get that data to sql server?

I'm sure there are much more efficient ways out there, but I lack the experience. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Dim foxConn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=vfpoledb.1;Data Source=Z:\update_dwprm01\dwprm01.DBF;Collating Sequence=general;")
Dim foxDa As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim foxDt As New DataTable
Dim foxCmd As New OleDbCommand
Dim foxReader As OleDbDataReader

Console.WriteLine("Copy dwprm01")
foxConn.Open()
foxDa = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM dwprm01", foxConn)
foxDa.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 90
foxDa.Fill(foxDt)
foxConn.Close()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to Visual FoxPro, use the Upsizing Wizard available here: http://vfpx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sedna&referringTitle=Home